# Is there a way to manually set the height of horizontal boxplots in ggplot2? (Vertical dodge)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, density-plot

I am trying to make a figure that will have density plots on the bottom  and corresponding boxplots above the density plots. My density plots and boxplots are filled/colored by a categorical variable. I cannot figure out a way to get the boxplots to be above the density plots and also dodged. This is what I've been able to get so far:

```
d <- mtcars
d$cyl <- as.factor(d$cyl)

fig <- ggplot(data = d) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg, fill = cyl),
               position = "dodge", 
               na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = mpg, color = cyl), 
               position = ggstance::position_dodgev(height = 1),
               width = .05, show.legend = FALSE,
               na.rm = TRUE) + 
  facet_grid(~am, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) 
fig
```

[image: Test figure]

But, as you can see, this does not uniformly move the boxplots above the density plots. I've also used

```
geom_boxplot(aes(x = mpg, color = cyl), 
            position = position_nudge(x = 0, y = .3),
            width = .05, show.legend = FALSE,
            na.rm = TRUE) +
```

but I end up having my boxplots overlap (they are no longer vertically dodged). Basically, I'm looking for a way to set a vertical height for my group of boxplots so they're above my density plots AND keep them vertically dodged from one another. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: can't you just do `facet_grid(cyl~am, scales = "free_x") + ` ?

Comment: @Edo thanks for the suggestion; however, this just gives a two-way facet (by row for cyl and column for am)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map the value you want your boxes to be centered around to `y`, inside the `aes` for `geom_boxplot`. E.g.:

```
ggplot(data = d) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = mpg, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = mpg, color = cyl, y = 1), 
               position = ggstance::position_dodgev(height = 0.2),
               width = .05, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_grid(~am, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Also, don't try to dodge `geom_density`.

Comment: I'm not being able to reproduce your graph. And `?geom_boxplot` says that it understands the aesthetics `x or y` (but not both is implied?). What versions of ggplot2 (3.3.2) and of ggstance (0.3.4) are you using

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hmmmm can't reproduce it now either, but mapping inside `aes` does work. Not sure what I messed up. Does the edit work? (If you look at the examples of `geom_boxplot` you'll see it is normal to use both `x` and `y`, unless I'm misunderstanding you.)

Comment: I can reproduce this answer using ggplot2 (3.3.2) and ggstance (0.3.4).

Comment: @Axeman, thank you so much! This worked perfectly for my data.

Comment: You're right, with y inside `aes` your code works, upvote.